# "error: no init found. Try passing init=bootarg" error after video driver update

Tags: 10.10, boot

I have dual boot Windows Vista and Ubuntu 10.10
 Now I have error message as follows:

```
No init found.  Try passing init=bootarg
BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1Ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash)
```

I booted from live CD and ran sudo blkid and the partitions are:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtilityÈ UUID="07D8-020DÈ TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY"UUID="447606C27606B4A8" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="5E5E0A7A5E0A4B6B" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="DataGR"UUID="0C1A17A111783c" TYPE="ntfs"
```

sda5 is my data partition.

The problems started after I tried to upgrade video drivers, then the hibernate or sleep function stopped working.   I had to restart the computer.   The last time I had to restart, I got the no init found error.

I tried several things, including gparted and check the sda3.  But no success.   Is there a way to recover the booting or do I need to reformat and re-install.   I did not want to loose my email profiles and email data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your ubuntu partition is missing. Are you sure this is a complete list of your partitions? Did you have a second hard disk that doesn't show up now?

Provide the output from `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` to check if there is unallocated disk space, maybe you can recover your partition if you accidentally deleted it.

Comment: Thanks   I forgot 1.   sda4 as W95 Ext'd (LBA)    But after I ran into problems I did not see one entitled Ubuntu or Linux.   I ran Gparted and it shows  partitions 1-5 where sda3 "OS" shows as boot and sda4 is "extended" with flag "lba"

Comment: Does that still mean the ubuntu partition is missing?   Do I simply re-install ubuntu?   Do I loose all email profiles and data?

Comment: I can't tell without the fdisk info

Comment: Here is the fdisk info:

Comment: I keep hitting the enter key to change line and it posts the message.  Sorry about that.  I ran sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

I got:
Device  Boot Start End Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1  1 10 80293+ de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2  11 1316 10485760 7 HTPS/NTFS
/dev/sda3 * 1316 23987 182108152 7 HTPS/NTFS
/dev/sda4  23987 30402 51522560 7 W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5  23988 30402 51522536 7 HTPS/NTFS

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any indication that a linux partition ever existed. Except if it was sda5 and accidentally did a format to ntfs or you have a second hd on the system. Sorry.

Comment: No.  No other drive.  What do you recommend?   Wld it mean that all email profiles and data are gone?

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu through Wubi?